# Native PHP function which get a key knowing a value in a array of array

Tags: php, arrays

there is a native function in php which having a array so defined:

```
$a = array ( 
   "row1" => array ( "col1" => "value1" ),
   "row2" => array ( "col2" => "value2" ),
   ...
   "rowN" => array ( "colN" => "valueN" ),
);
```

Like know for example "valueN" to get "rowN" ? I solved checking with dual cycle, but interest to know if in PHP there is a native function whick do it.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Showing the code you used would at least help us understand what kind of alternative or optimization you might be seeking. I, for one, found it very difficult to understand what you're saying with this question.

Comment: No, there's no function to do this. You could do it if each of the sub-arrays had the same key, but not when they all have different keys.

Comment: To support @Barmar's comment, if all sub-arrays had the same key, you could do this `$key = array_search('valueN', array_column($array, 'colName'));`

Comment: For example i have a key as:  "animals"  and into array i have values as: "dog", "cat", "horse".
Giving to input for example "cat" i ask just if i can get the key "animals".

Comment: No, there's no function that does that for 2-dimensional arrays. `array_search` works for 1-dimensional arrays, but it won't search inside the nested array.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois i don't know 'valueN' and need get it searching for value. In this sense it not help me. I ask about native function in pHp becouse is easy solve writing the code with two foreach which reading all structure.

Comment: @Barmar oki, mean which not there is it. Thanks.

Comment: what if there would be multiple same values, should it return a set of keys?

Comment: `array_keys(array_filter($a, function($row) use ($search) { return in_array($search, $row); }));` as long as every entry is an array in its own right